# Can someone Explain Mutex and how it is used?

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading, mutex

I read a few documents about Mutex and still the only Idea I have got is that it helps preventing threads from accessing a resource that is already being used by another resource.

I got from Code snippet and executed which works fine:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <process.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


BOOL FunctionToWriteToDatabase(HANDLE hMutex)
{
    DWORD dwWaitResult;
    // Request ownership of mutex.
    dwWaitResult = WaitForSingleObject(
    hMutex, // handle to mutex
    5000L); // five-second time-out interval
        switch (dwWaitResult)
        {
        // The thread got mutex ownership.
            case WAIT_OBJECT_0:
            __try
            {
                // Write to the database.
            }
            __finally {
            // Release ownership of the mutex object.
            if (! ReleaseMutex(hMutex)) {
            // Deal with error.
        }
            break;
        }
            // Cannot get mutex ownership due to time-out.
            case WAIT_TIMEOUT:
            return FALSE;
            // Got ownership of the abandoned mutex object.
            case WAIT_ABANDONED:
            return FALSE;
        }
    return TRUE;
}

void main()
{
    HANDLE hMutex;

    hMutex=CreateMutex(NULL,FALSE,"MutexExample");

    if (hMutex == NULL)
    {
        printf("CreateMutex error: %d\n", GetLastError() );
    }
    else if ( GetLastError() == ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS )
        printf("CreateMutex opened existing mutex\n");

    else
        printf("CreateMutex created new mutex\n");

}
```

But What I don't understand is where is the thread and where is the shared resource? Can anyone please explain or provide a better article or document?

Comment: Your code snippet seems incomplete, e.g. I can't see where FunctionToWriteToDatabase is called. Can you provide more and where did you get it from? It would also be helpful if you clarified whether your question is about mutexes in general or this particular code snippet.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A mutex provides **mut**ually **ex**clusive access to a resource; in your case, a database.  There aren't multiple threads in your program, but you can have multiple instances of your program running, which is what your mutex is protecting against.  Effectively, it is still protecting against access from more than one thread, it's just that those threads can be in separate processes.

Your code is creating a *named* mutex that can be shared across multiple instances of your application.  This is a form of interprocess communication.  MSDN documentation on [`CreateMutex`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682411(VS.85).aspx) has additional helpful information about named mutexes:

> Two or more processes can call
>   CreateMutex to create the same named
>   mutex. The first process actually
>   creates the mutex, and subsequent
>   processes with sufficient access
>   rights simply open a handle to the
>   existing mutex...
>
> Multiple processes can have handles of
>   the same mutex object, enabling use of
>   the object for interprocess
>   synchronization.

A mutex is only necessary here if the database you're working against doesn't inherently support multithreaded access.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe It will be the best source to you

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutual_exclusion

Answer (score 0):

You can refer this SO post for comparison of various thread synchronization mechanisms
[Difference between Locks, Mutex and Critical Sections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2808617/difference-between-locks-mutex-and-critical-sections)

If you want specific information Mutex then wikipedia will give you enough details.

Answer (score 0):

This [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686927%28VS.85%29.aspx) in msdn provides a similar example as yours with threads made in the main() function.  But again the shared resource, which is supposed to be a database is not included.
Anyway, a shared resource is whatever that needs to be accessed from multiple threads: settingsfiles, drivers, database,...

Mind you that the counter in the example is written while protected by the mutex, while it is been read while not being protected.  While in this case, there is probably no problem, it is a bit sloppy.