# Suspend process after a specific child process is started

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, process

I have a loader.exe which starts a process A by using CreateProcess(..)
Process A starts after a while another process B.

I would like to suspend process A and process B when B will be started by process A.
How can I wait for B? I would like to be notified or do I have to poll until the process is there?

At runtime I know the name of process B and I know that B will be started by process A.

Thanks

Comment: Do you have control over the code in process A?

Comment: I don't have control over the code in process A and process B. I just wrote the loader.exe.

Comment: Do you need to suspend A and B as soon as B starts (i.e., before B's initialization) or can it be a second or so later?

Answer (score 0):

Use [Boost Interprocess library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/doc/html/interprocess.html). Of special interest to you are mutexes, conditions, and semaphores.

Comment: Sorry, I would like to avoid 3rd party libraries.

Comment: Note that Boost.Interprocess is a header only library - no binaries. Just include your Boost header directory in your compiler include path. This also means, by the way, that you can simply copy their code (or learn from their implementation).

Answer (score 0):

If you are not keen on using Boost, you can think of win32 mutex. Please refer this thread for more information on how to use this. [Mutex explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3528877/can-some-one-explain-mutex-and-how-that-is-used)

Basically you can create mutex with a given name from process B and wait for the same mutex from A/Loader.